# Prohibiting line break at specific point of url while using \url command

Tags: line-breaking, urls

I have a `\url{some.edu/page}` that breaks just before `.edu`  I would like to have it break at the `/` at worst, or not at all. How can I do that?

Comment: Thank you for editing. I'm new, will try to format better in the future.

Comment: You're very welcome :) [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The characters, where breaks are allowed, can be changed. See [documentation of package `url`, section "5.2 Changing linebreaks"](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/url/url.pdf). In this case the dot is part of `\UrlBreaks`. The following redefines it without the dot:

```
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand*{\UrlBreaks}{\do\@\do\\\do\/\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]%
  \do\)\do\,\do\?\do\'\do+\do\=\do\#}%
```